# How to detect what maven profiles are activated?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-profiles

I use a very complex maven project and I would like to know what maven profiles are activated when I do `mvn install`.

How to find this out?

Answer (score 12):

You can simply check by using:

```
mvn help:active-profiles
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks! If you'd like to see the profile before carrying out your regular steps, as with all maven tasks you can chain them e.g: `mvn help:active-profiles clean package`. This will print the active profile at the beginning of your output and you can be sure the subsequent steps are running in your desired context.

Answer (score 3):

this will help

```
 mvn help:active-profiles
```

for more details refer 
[Maven Build profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Answer (score 0):

Enable the debug mode with

```
mvn -X install
```